# How are unknown attributes supposed to be treated before C++17?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++-attributes

cppreference [says](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) that

> All attributes unknown to an implementation are ignored without causing an error.

... but that this edict was introduced in C++17. What about earlier versions of C++? Are unknown attributes supposed to be errors? Is it implementation-defined what to do with them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was implementation-defined since its introduction in C++11.

See [[dcl.attr.grammar]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.attr#grammar-5):

> For an attribute-token not specified in this International Standard, the behavior is implementation-defined.